# Attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'gainWeight'

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, attributeerror

Why does my code give me the errror `Attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'gainWeight'` ?

Class code:

```
class Pig():

def __init__(self, name, age, weight, value):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.weight = weight
    self.value = value

def Weight(self):
    self.weight = randrange(50,250)

def growOlder(self):
    self.age += 1

def gainWeight(self, weight):
    self.weight += 5

def runAndGainValue(self):
    self.value += 5

def __str__(self):
    a = self.name + " "
    a += str(self.age) + " "
    a += str(self.weight) + " "
    a += str(self.value) + " "
    return a
```

And the code in the main program:

```
def work_function():
    work = input("What do you want to do for work today?"
        "\nPress 1 to feed your animals"
        "\nPress 2 to take them out in the yard"
        "\nPress 3 to your animals to sleep"
        "\nPress 4 to go back to main menu.\n")
    if work == "1":
        yourfarm.printAnimals()
        print ("are all very happy to be fed and have gained some weight!\nLook at the weight now and see for yourself!")
        p.gainWeight(+5)
            #Here is where the problem lies.
        yourfarm.printAnimals()
```

p is a list with the items for my animals.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: If `p` is a list, then you can't call `gainWeight` on it, since lists don't have that method.

Comment: Try `p[0]` (or any other animals you want). That'll work.

Comment: Not related to your question, but please note that your `gainWeight` method ignores the `weight` argument.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Okey not sure what you mean, what will it do to my program? And is there anyway so solve the problem?

Comment: @Bodenn Then have a look at this method and think about what it does when I call `.gainWeight(10)` and what it is (probably) supposed to be.

Comment: @Bondenn glglgl already described the problem. Use `self.weight += weight` instead of `self.weight += 5` to solve it.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Ah I see, thank you! Is it the same code I use if I want the runAndGainValue function to work aswell? Because when I try the same code on that one I get "cant convert int object to str implicity" :S

Comment: @Bondenn probably you passed a string instead of an integer to the constructor.  If this problem persists, please open a new question containing the code where you create the `Pig` objects.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Ok I'll open a new question because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second snippet, you need to access the elements of the list, not the list itself:

```
for pig in p:
    pig.gainWeight(5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can accept your answer in about 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through all your elements, and call `gainWeight` on them, since it is a `Pig` that has the method, not the list:

```
for pig in p:
    pig.gainWeight(5)
```